# Build failed, gulp watch throwing this errors

Tags: webpack, gulp-watch, laravel-mix

Having this error whenever trying to build( recently fixed the compilation error by downgrading to uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1 and installing webpack@2.7 ), adding suggested configuration for bubble is not working as well, can someone show the right path? Thanks in advance. :)

```
    ERROR in ./~/buble-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./~/vue-google-autocomplete/src/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue
```

Module build failed:

```
 333 :                 let types = [this.types];
    334 :                 if (types.includes('(cities)')) types = types.concat(CITIES_TYPE);
    335 :                 if (types.includes('(regions)')) types = types.concat(REGIONS_TYPE);
    336 :
    337 :                 for (let r of results) {

    for...of statements are not supported. Use `transforms: { forOf: false }` to skip transformation and disable this error, or `transforms: { dangerousForOf: true }` if you know what you're doing (337:16)
     @ ./~/vue-google-autocomplete/src/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue 5:18-115
     @ ./~/buble-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/views/auth/Login.vue
     @ ./resources/assets/js/views/auth/Login.vue
     @ ./resources/assets/js/routes/routes.js
     @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "buble": "^0.15.2",
    "buble-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^1.11.3",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-16",
    "laravel-elixir-imagemin": "^0.2.3",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vue-axios": "^1.2.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-star-rating": "^1.0.6",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.9.2",
    "@chenfengyuan/vue-carousel": "^1.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "firebase": "^4.11.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "qrcode.vue": "^1.6.1",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "v-toaster": "^1.0.3",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.0-rc.33",
    "v2-datepicker": "^3.1.1",
    "vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-burger-menu": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-ckeditor": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-clipboards": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-content-loader": "^0.2.2",
    "vue-datepicker": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-form-generator": "^2.3.4",
    "vue-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.3",
    "vue-good-table": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-google-autocomplete": "^1.0.13",
    "vue-html-to-paper": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-js-popover": "^1.1.6",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-json-to-csv": "^1.1.7",
    "vue-lazyload": "^1.2.6",
    "vue-lodash": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-masked-input": "^0.5.2",
    "vue-md-date-picker": "^1.0.16",
    "vue-meta": "^1.6.0",
    "vue-momentjs": "^0.1.1",
    "vue-monthly-picker": "^0.1.7",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.0.8",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-notifications": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-paginate": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.3",
    "vue-shortkey": "^3.1.7",
    "vue-simple-spinner": "^1.2.8",
    "vue-simple-timeline": "^0.1.2",
    "vue-sweetalert": "^0.1.18",
    "vue-switches": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-tables-2": "^1.4.56",
    "vue-tabs-component": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.26",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.9",
    "vue2-simplert": "^0.6.1",
    "vuex": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```